# Lifting of operator under free action

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, group-actions

Suppose a Lie group $K$ acts freely, properly and isometrically on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, which is equipped with a $K$-invariant measure. Then $(M/K,\check{g})$ is a Riemannian manifold, where the metric $\check{g}$ and the measure descend from the metric and measure on $M$ in the natural way.

**Question:** Can one interpret a bounded linear operator $T$ on $L^2(M/K)$ as a bounded linear operator $\tilde{T}$ on $L^2(M)$ that is invariant under the action of $K$?

Thoughts: What I mean by being invariant under the action of $K$ is that the action of $T$ on $L^2(M)$ commutes with action of $k$ on $L^2(M)$ (defined by $kf(x):=f(k^{-1}x)$) for every $k\in K$. One can check that a $K$-invariant operator on $L^2(M)$ always descends to an operator on $L^2(M/K)$. I wonder if there is a reference that addresses the issue of lifting an operator the other way.

Comment: No, there are many more of the latter than the former. This issue already arises if $M$ is taken to be a finite set and $K$ a finite group.

Comment: I take it you mean there are many more of the former than the latter? In that case, if $M$ is a finite set and $K$ is a finite group, then $M\cong N\times K$, for some finite set $N$ and $l^2(M)\cong l^2(K)\otimes l^2(N)$. I feel like every bounded operator $T$ on $l^2(N)$ lifts to the bounded operator $1\otimes T\in B(l^2(K)\otimes l^2(N))$?

Comment: To keep it really simple let's take $N = 1$. Then $L^2(N)$ is $1$-dimensional so the space of linear operators on it is also $1$-dimensional. But the space of $K$-invariant linear operators $L^2(K) \to L^2(K)$ is $|K|$-dimensional (exercise). So there are many more of the latter than the former. I recognize I've slightly misread your question: what I'm claiming is that lifts can't be unique.

Comment: By "can one interpret" I meant, is there a $\tilde{T}$ that descends to your given $T$. In the case of $N=1$ I think this is true.

Comment: I originally read your question as asking whether the two were equivalent / whether there's a natural isomorphism between them.

Comment: I see, the question was a bit vague. Yes mainly I'm concerned with whether there exists a lift at all. The answer seems to be a clear yes in the case of $M=N\times K$, which makes me think that for general free actions (or maybe even just proper actions?) that this might be possible. But I couldn't find a simple way to think about it (or a reference).